# VBA Update Related Table without Creating new Entry on CommandSave

Tags: vba, relational-database

Example:

So Apples Oranges Bannana Tables insert their keys into Fruit Table

Fruit
ID AppleID OrangeID BannanaID FruitNum
1____1_________________________3
2____________4_________________3
3_____________________5________3

What I would like is for it to check for FruitNum 3 and update the table

ID AppleID OrangeID BannanaID FruitNum
1____1_______4______5__________3

I got that to work with an update Statement but when I go and acRecordSave

ID AppleID OrangeID BannanaID FruitNum
1____1_______4______5__________3
2___________________5__________3
etc.

Each Fruit is a Form and each entry has a Fruit Number that goes with it.  So when you fill out the Orange Form with 4 and then FruitNum 3, it should check to see if a FruitNum3 exists and update that table. And the CMD save should then not create a new record in the FruitNum table if it already exists.  Should I add a delete record after?

```
  CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [tableFruitNum] SET [" & NameFruit & "] = " & ID & " WHERE [FruitNum]=" & FruitNum
```

'How to Update a Table (For Future Reference)
'Update table_name
'SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
'WHERE some_column=some_value;

Answer (score 0):

So being new to access, I had created a relational table that was bound to the form.  On loading of the form it would create a new record on the parent table and save, which even after I would update the "FruitTable" would create a new record on top of updating a past Fruit reference.

So after some research; I figured I had to unbind the FruitNum from the form, and do either an Update or Insert into the Fruit Table.

After that I had to edit the form and manually do a search.

I dont think I explained my issue to well with the example but in case anyone looks and this pops up anywhere.  Was my first attempt at asking a question.